# Is there any way to prevent the trailing ants border effect on links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I'm talking about:

[image: http://i56.tinypic.com/vi2rrq.jpg]

It's a javascript void link:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>`

so it doesn't take the user anywhere. When clicked it shows off that traling ants border. Is there any way to prevent this using either css or javascript?

Answer (score 3):

The simple CSS answer is:

```
a{
    outline: 0;
}
```

---

### Addition:

You should probably be using a [CSS reset](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/) but the web development world is pretty split on that.  I like using [Eric Meyer's ResetCSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: he he, I've been doing CSS for over 3 years and I was unaware of that rule. thanks!

Comment: To add to this, the outline rule is there for usability. It shows up on focus so the user is aware of what is being selected. This is especially important if a user is tabbing through links or input fields on a page. Of course, having a stupid dotted border can be unattractive on navigation or images, but having some sort of stylistic differentiation for the element in focus is important. As Lucas demonstrated, it is possible to target elements in their focus state with the :focus pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove them from everywhere:

```
*:focus { outline: none; }
*::-moz-focus-inner { border: none; }
```